# How to find the element count of an array using the Map object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a paragraph of words and would like to find the count of each word, specifically using JavaScript's `Map` object.

I understand that this can be achieved using the `.get()` and `.set()` methods, but I am not sure how to implement this.

Below is my code.

```
let paragraph = `Lorem ipsum donec nisi taciti et elit congue turpis, lobortis 
                 massa suscipit massa est a praesent metus egestas, conubia turpis 
                 in cursus libero pharetra praesent.
                 Per bibendum taciti sit taciti facilisis a bibendum nisl massa non 
                 aliquam sem auctor ipsum eros, massa sed cubilia porta primis 
                 felis elementum non fringilla conubia neque aenean urna.`

// Split the paragraph into an array of individual words.

let words = paragraph.match(/\w+/gi);

let map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  let word = words[i];
  map.set(word, 0);
  // Logic - if (map contains word) {
  // map.set(word, count += 1);
  // } else {
  // map.set(word, 1);
  // }
}

console.log(map);
```

Comment: So you would like to know how characters each word has?

Comment: @jburtondev Not quite. I’m after the count of each word in the paragraph

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with Map.

For each iteration set the word in the map.

`a.get("Lorem")` will return a number or undefined. The `||` handles if it's undefined. Then add 1.

[Map#set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) also returns the map object.

```js
const paragraph = `Lorem ipsum donec nisi taciti et elit congue turpis, lobortis massa suscipit massa est a praesent metus egestas, conubia turpis in cursus libero pharetra praesent.
Per bibendum taciti sit taciti facilisis a bibendum nisl massa non aliquam sem auctor ipsum eros, massa sed cubilia porta primis felis elementum non fringilla conubia neque aenean urna.`

const words = paragraph.match(/\w+/gi);

const res = words.reduce((a,c)=>{
  return a.set(c, (a.get(c)||0) + 1);
}, new Map());

console.log([...res]);
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With `Map` datastructure, you can write your code:

```
const paragraph = "Lorem ipsum donec nisi taciti et elit congue turpis, lobortis massa suscipit massa est a praesent metus egestas, conubia turpis in cursus libero pharetra praesent. Per bibendum taciti sit taciti facilisis a bibendum nisl massa non aliquam sem auctor ipsum eros, massa sed cubilia porta primis felis elementum non fringilla conubia neque aenean urna."

// Split the paragraph into an array of individual words.

let words = paragraph.match(/\w+/gi);

let map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let word = words[i];
    // Here you check if map already got the word.
    if (map.has(word)) {
        map.set(word, map.get(word) + 1)
    } else {
        map.set(word, 0);
    }
}

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Map has the key and if so get it and add 1, otherwise just add it.

```js
let paragraph = `Lorem ipsum donec nisi taciti et elit congue turpis, lobortis massa suscipit massa est a praesent metus egestas, conubia turpis in cursus libero pharetra praesent.
Per bibendum taciti sit taciti facilisis a bibendum nisl massa non aliquam sem auctor ipsum eros, massa sed cubilia porta primis felis elementum non fringilla conubia neque aenean urna.`

// Split the paragraph into an array of individual words.

let words = paragraph.match(/\w+/gi);

let map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let word = words[i];
    // Logic - if (map contains word) {
    if(map.get(word)){
        map.set(word, map.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
        map.set(word, 1);
    }
}

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Map already has the key than add `1` to particular and if not add a new key value into Map.

```js
let paragraph = `Lorem ipsum donec nisi taciti et elit congue turpis, lobortis massa suscipit massa est a praesent metus egestas, conubia turpis in cursus libero pharetra praesent.
Per bibendum taciti sit taciti facilisis a bibendum nisl massa non aliquam sem auctor ipsum eros, massa sed cubilia porta primis felis elementum non fringilla conubia neque aenean urna.`


let words = paragraph.match(/\w+/gi);

let map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  let word = words[i];
  if(map.get(word)) {
    map.set(word, map.get(word)+1);
  } else {
    map.set(word, 1);
  }
}

console.log(...map);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set values in map**

```
paragraph.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
    yourMap.set(word, word.length);
});
```

**Extract values from map**

```
Array.from(myMap.keys()).forEach((key, value) => {
    console.log(`Count of word ${key} is: ${value}`);
});
```

Comment: How is the index related to the word count?

Comment: I think the question is related to "element count". Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: I have clarified with the questioner and updated my answer accordingly.